# Ler arquivo de texto via HTTP

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um aplicativo para Android com o Android Studio e estou tendo problemas para ler um arquivo de texto que está hospedado na Internet. Sempre que eu tento executar o método **checkVersion()** ele retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException]
A mensagem está vazia pois `net.getMessage()` está retornando `null`

*iPoema.java*

```
public int getVersion() {
    int versao = 0;
    String linha = "0";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.xadees.xpg.com.br/iPoema.txt");
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String sb;
        while ((sb = in.readLine()) != null) {
            linha += sb;
        }
        in.close();
        versao = Integer.parseInt(linha);
    } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException net) {
        showMessage(net.getClass().getName(), net.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException io) {
        showMessage(io.getClass().getName(), io.getMessage());
    } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        showMessage(use.getClass().getName(), use.getMessage());
    }
    return versao;
}
```

Comment: Dependendo do sistema usado e da versão HTTP, você pode não estar dando as informações mínimas requeridas (não conheço Java muito bem).

Answer (score 3):

Operações de rede no Android devem ser assíncronas, ou seja, não podem ser executadas na thread principal para não correr o risco de congelar a tela do usuário durante a operação. Utilize uma [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) para rodar o seu código fora da thread principal (main thread).

Eis o mais simples dos exemplos:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> MinhaTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Qualquer código aqui é executado fora da thread principal (Views não podem ser atualizadas)
        return "qualquer coisa";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //Após o return do método doInBackground, qualquer código aqui estará novamente na main thread (Views podem ser atualizadas)
    }
};

MinhaTask.execute();
```

Comment: Poderia me ajudar a como colocar esse código no meu projeto? Link: http://pastebin.com/6PmsitYy (código recortado, metódo utilizado para checar versão e atualizar o aplicativo)

Comment: @iXaDe simplesmente copie todo o conteúdo de `getVersion` para dentro do `doInBackground`. O parâmetro `s` do `onPostExecute` vai ser a sua versão.

Comment: Eu tentei aqui e funcionou corretamente, PORÉM ele só pode ser executado uma única vez por execução, sendo que a pessoa pode estar querendo checar a versão mais de uma vez.

Comment: Mas meu app também fará o download de um XML para a leitura dos dados e exibí-lo, então eu irei utilizar o AsyncTask para isso e a pessoa pode ficar checando se tem postagem nova, daí a necessidade de que ele execute mais de uma vez. Qualquer coisa, meu código do AsyncTask para a atualização do app está aqui: http://pastebin.com/0X2x2g79

Comment: @iXaDe O que você quer dizer com `só pode ser executado uma única vez por execução`? Não existe restrição para o uso do AsyncTask, você está recebendo alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Sim, porém não é exibida, somente o app que fecha sozinho. Ele realiza do download do `iPoema.xml`, porém não consegue realizar a leitura. Será que eu preciso de 4 AsyncTask?
`1 - iPoema.txt; 2 - iPoema.xml; 3 - iPoema.apk; 4 - Leitura do XML`

Comment: Hoje eu quis testar a execução do download do XML e funcionou. Depois eu testei a leitura dele e o aplicativo acaba fechando. Qual seria o modo correto de se usar o JDOM2 com AsyncTask? ( Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/rTNtEFyu )